# Android sound mediaplayer IllegalStateException and no sound

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity  MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.caneraydin.androidwithlogin.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:138)

For this code

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mainactivitymp3);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        try {
          mMediaPlayer.prepare();
          Log.d(TAG,"mainonresumemediaplayer");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.d(TAG,"mainonresume mediaplayer error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMediaPlayer.start();//.release();// STOPSHIP: 6/2/2016
```

i only have here, not antything else. 
So i moved all code to onCreate, but still same error for

```
prepare
```

line.

When i delete prepare,

```
  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mainactivitymp3);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.start();//.release();// STOPSHIP: 6/2/2016
```

There is no sound. it writes when i only start mainactivity (mainactivity stays active forever until clicked smething)

> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
>
> MediaPlayer finalized without being released(i did not finish
>   mainactivity, still active)

```
.493 760-769/? V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_finalize
.493 760-769/? V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
.543 760-769/? V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_finalize
.543 760-769/? V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
.543 24067-24067/com.example W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
.543 760-769/? V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_finalize
.543 760-769/? V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
.733 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
.733 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: constructor
.743 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: setListener
.753 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
.753 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: constructor
.753 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: setListener
.753 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setDataSourceFD: fd 49
.753 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(49, 597544, 1376079)
.763 168-556/? V/MediaPlayerService: Create new client(312) from pid 24067, uid 10177, 
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: setDataSource fd=39, offset=597544, length=1376079
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: st_dev  = 45849
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: st_mode = 33188
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: st_uid  = 1000
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: st_gid  = 1000
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: st_size = 3186530
.763 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: player type = 3
.773 168-430/? V/AudioSink: AudioOutput(1947)
.773 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] notify (0xb7d93b78, 8, 0, 0)
.773 24067-24079/com.example V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
.773 24067-24079/com.example V/MediaPlayer: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
.833 167-19415/? D/WVMDrmPlugIn: WVMDrmPlugin::onInitialize : 6449
.833 167-19415/? D/WVMDrmPlugIn: WVMDrmPlugin::onSetOnInfoListener : add 6449
.843 167-167/? D/WVMDrmPlugIn: WVMDrmPlugin::onTerminate : 6449
.843 168-430/? V/MediaExtractor: Autodetected media content as 'audio/mpeg' with confidence 0.20
.843 168-30639/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] getParameter(1700)
.843 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
.843 168-868/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x0)
.843 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: prepare
.843 168-168/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] setAudioStreamType(3)
.843 168-20316/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] prepareAsync
.873 168-24099/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] notify (0xb7d93b78, 5, 0, 0)
.873 168-24099/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] notify (0xb7d93b78, 1, 0, 0)
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: New video size 0 x 0
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: callback application
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: prepared
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: signal application thread
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: callback application
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: prepare complete - status=0
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
.873 24067-24078/com.example V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setLooping: 1
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setLooping
.873 168-556/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] setLooping(1)
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
.873 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer: start
.873 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] setLooping(1)
.873 168-30639/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
.873 168-30639/? V/AudioSink: setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
.873 168-30639/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
.873 168-30639/? V/AudioSink: setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
.873 168-168/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] start
.883 168-168/? V/MediaPlayerService: [312] notify (0xb7d93b78, 6, 0, 0)
.883 24067-24079/com.example V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
.883 24067-24067/com.example D/Chic: MAINACTIVITY OnCreate*************
.883 24067-24079/com.example V/MediaPlayer: Received MEDIA_STARTED
.883 24067-24079/com.example V/MediaPlayer: callback application
.883 24067-24079/com.example V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
06-02 09:25:27.324 24067-24067/com.example I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
06-02 09:25:27.324 24067-24067/com.example E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
06-02 09:25:27.424 24067-24067/com.example D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-02 09:25:27.494 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 720 (msec)
06-02 09:25:27.494 24067-24067/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
06-02 09:25:27.534 24067-24146/com.example I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 13.910MB for 3112976-byte allocation
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_finalize
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24146/com.example D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3480K, 32% free 9389K/13768K, paused 25ms, total 35ms
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: setListener
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: disconnect
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: destructor
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: disconnect
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_finalize
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: setListener
06-02 09:25:27.624 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: disconnect
06-02 09:25:27.624 168-430/? V/MediaPlayerService: disconnect(312) from pid 24067
06-02 09:25:27.644 168-430/? I/AudioPlayer: reset out
06-02 09:25:27.644 168-430/? I/SecMediaClock: SecMediaClock destructor
06-02 09:25:27.644 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: destructor
06-02 09:25:27.644 24067-24076/com.example V/MediaPlayer: disconnect
06-02 09:25:27.644 168-30639/? V/MediaPlayerService: Client(312) destructor pid = 24067
06-02 09:25:27.644 168-30639/? V/AudioSink: +++ close
06-02 09:25:27.644 168-30639/? V/AudioSink: --- close
06-02 09:25:27.644 168-30639/? V/MediaPlayerService: disconnect(312) from pid 24067
```

I did not add any permission. MY current ones:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

[Android rebuild project, package org.junit does not exist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584385/android-rebuild-project-package-org-junit-does-not-exist-error)

can this be reason?

I could only hear for 0.5 second. I rerun lots of times and only one i could here.

Comment: You don't call `prepare()` for `MediaPlayer`s you've created with `MediaPlayer.create()`. The `create()` method takes care of it for you.

Comment: Please look at my edited question. I also used without prepare.

Comment: don't remove prepare(), remove  mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); and check

Comment: @Rohan did not work. Errors again. When i block commented try catch and rerun, again i heard for one secound. But after that, i couldnot hear when i run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
    try{
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalimba);
       mediaPlayer.start();          
    }  catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Again for one second i can hear at first run. Next runnings can not give sound, even for a second.